# Custom Progress Bar with nine-patch image

Tags: android, android-progressbar

Can I use a 9-patch image as the android:progress for custom progress bar in android?
Also, how can I implement a progress with Gradient color from left to right or horizontal gradient?

Comment: Here's a good tutorial: [http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/custom-progress-bar-in-android.html](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/custom-progress-bar-in-android.html)

Comment: Thanks, that's is a good tutorial but not what I want..

Comment: I think you can adapt it to your needs, just use a gradient inside the xml drawable.